# CodeSign with non-login keychain

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, codesign

*I prayed to the twin gods of stack overflow and Google for many an hour, but for naught.*

I have a dedicated build machine and I'm trying to setup CI on it.  Obviously codesign fails to run, as the login keychain is locked.

Created a new keychain and moved the following to it:

- iPhone Developer certificate
- iOS Developer private key
- Developer ID Certification Authority
- Apple Worldwide Developer Relations...

Login via ssh to the server.

Run xcodebuild and it fails with *Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code*

Run *security unlock-keychain -p XXXXXX /Users/xxx/Library/Keychains/automation.keychain-db*

Run xcodebuild and it still fails with *Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code*

Run *security unlock-keychain -p XXXXXX /Users/xxx/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db*

Run xcodebuild and it now passes successfully. What am I missing? What else should be in the automation keychain that isn't there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added your keychain to the search list? like

```
security list-keychains -d user -s "$MY_KEYCHAIN" $(security list-keychains -d user | sed s/\"//g)
```

Comment: Well, that was a well spent day. Is this a one time action? Once per login or before every unlock?

Comment: I do this once per login because i delete my custom keychain after code signing.